# rdlc report does not show anything

Tags: c#, sql-server, rdlc

My data `gridview` does work but `rdlc` report does not show any thing.
i have a `report.rdlc` file and a `dataset(DataSet1)` that contains a `datatable(DataTable1)`. My data table has two column `Wname` and `Ccode` both of them are `string`:

```
SqlConnection scon = new SqlConnection(@"data source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\PCPdb.mdf;integrated security=True;connect timeout=30;MultipleActiveResultSets=True");
string query = "SELECT Wname,Ccode FROM tbl_Worker wk inner join tbl_Contract cont on wk.Wcode=cont.CWcode WHERE wk.Wcode=1122";
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.TableName = "DataTable1";
SqlCommand scm = new SqlCommand(query, scon);
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(scm);
scon.Open();
scm.ExecuteNonQuery();
sda.Fill(dt);
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource();
rds.Name = "DataSet1";
rds.Value = dt;
reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
scon.Close();
```

Comment: In my experience, this most often happens when the dataset names on the report do not match exactly with the names provided in the data source, though it can have other causes.  Unfortunately, SSRS has a reputation for being very difficult to debug.

Comment: but it is exactly the same

Comment: Like I said, that is just the most common reason I've seen for this, there are lots of possible reasons.  Without having access for your RDLC it is going to be almost impossible to diagnose.